# jQuery/Bootstrap 3 - find previous sibling on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to prepend a span depending on the next `<ul>`sibling having class "collapse" or classes "collapse in".

I can already put the span I need in the previous `<a>` if the sibling `<ul>` has any class.
But now I need to change the span when I click the `<a>` to expand the `<ul>`.

For a better understanding here's a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qtrhu249/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="treeview">
<ul class="level1">
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" href=".options1">
      Item 1
    </a>
    <ul class="collapse options1">
      <li>
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href=".sublevel1"></a>
        <input type="checkbox" value="option1" />
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href=".sublevel1">Item 1-1</a>
        <ul class="collapse sublevel1">
          <li>
              Item 1-1-1
            <ul>
              <li><input type="checkbox" value="option1" />
                Item 1-1-1-1
              </li>
              <li><a data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapse1-1-1-1-1"></a>
              <input type="checkbox" value="option1" />
                <a data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapse1-1-1-1-1">Item 1-1-1-2</a>
                <ul class="collapse collapse1-1-1-1-1">
                  <li>Item 1-1-1-2-1
                    <ul>
                      <li><input type="checkbox" value="option1" />Item 1-1-1-2-1-1</li>
                      <li><a data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapse1-1-1-1-1-1-1"></a><input type="checkbox" value="option1" />
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href=".collapse1-1-1-1-1-1-1">Item 1-1-1-2-1-2</a>
                        <ul class="collapse collapse1-1-1-1-1-1-1">
                          <li>Item 1-1-1-2-1-2-1
                            <ul>
                              <li><input type="checkbox" value="option1" />Item 1-1-1-2-1-2-1-1</li>
                              <li><input type="checkbox" value="option1" />Item 1-1-1-2-1-2-1-2</li>
                              <li><input type="checkbox" value="option1" />Item 1-1-1-2-1-2-1-3</li>
                              <li><input type="checkbox" value="option1" />Item 1-1-1-2-1-2-1-4</li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="option1" />Item 1-2</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="option1" />Item 1-3</li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" value="option1" />Item 1-4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
$('.treeview ul').not('ul:not([class])').each(function() {
    $(this).find("a").first().prepend("<span>XYZ</span>");
})
```

The objective: 
The elements that have `XYZ` when clicked, change to `ZYX` and backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text of your span with `html()` . Try this:

```
//Function on click a elements with data-toggle
$('a[data-toggle]').on('click',function(){

     //Target the span inside the clicked a
     var sp = $('span',this)

     //Toggle the Text 
     sp.html() == "XYZ" ? sp.html('ZYX') : sp.html('XYZ');
 })
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qtrhu249/2/)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I exactly understood your question, but I made some changes in your `JavaScript` code. See it below:

```
$('.treeview ul').not('ul:not([class])').each(function() {
  $(this).find("a").first().prepend("<span>XYZ</span>");
});
$('a[data-toggle]').on('click',function(){
  var sp = $('span', this);
  if (!sp[0])
    sp = $('span', $(this).prevAll('a'));
  sp.html() == "XYZ" ? sp.html('ZYX') : sp.html('XYZ');
});
```